# Shell Script - command not found

Tags: shell, cygwin

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello from sh"
```

---

When I run this program (hello.sh) I get a command not found error. I'm using cygwin on Windows and I looked at cy's FAQ. It said to change the permissions to 755. I already did that and still no luck. I get the same error with these other two programs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello from python"
```

---

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
print "Hello from perl\n";
```

---

Any answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think that bash.exe does not have the PATH set up

Comment: How do I solve that issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run bash shell scripts in cygwin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467390/how-do-i-run-bash-shell-scripts-in-cygwin)

Comment: Duplicate (more recent but that has a better answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467390/how-do-i-run-bash-shell-scripts-in-cygwin

Answer (score 4):

As has already been said, you need to add the Cygwin binaries to your path. To do so, right click on "My Computer", click "Properties", then "Advanced", then "Environment Variables".

Create a new environment variable with name `CYGWIN_HOME` and value `C:\cygwin` (or wherever you installed cygwin. The default location is `C:\cygwin\` so this should probably work for you).

Then edit the environment variable named "PATH", and tack on the following to the end:

```
;%CYGWIN_HOME%\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\sbin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\bin;%CYGWIN_HOME%\usr\local\sbin
```

Close your command prompt, then reopen it. The cygwin binaries should now be available. You can double-check this by typing "which bash". It should report the location of your bash executable

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the "command not found" error on a Perl script. That script has the shebang line: "#!/usr/bin/env perl" as the first line and my user is the owner who has execute permissions. I was trying to run the script using the command line "ppminstall.pl ?" (the script is set up to display documentation for using the script if passed the '?' argument). I was cd'd to the directory containing the script. The solution turned out to be to run it using "./ppminstall.pl ?", i.e. explicitly specify the current directory. I think that you might be able to add "." to the current path and get the original command line to work, but it does seem safer to me to use "./" to run it since it's pretty explicit about where the script that you want to run is located. It may be possible for someone to manipulate your Path variable and cause you to be running a version of the script that you didn't intend. The '.' and '/' characters are easy to type without taking your eyes off the screen, so it seems like a useful habit to get into. Of course, I don't know if that is your problem, but it was mine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by the wrong line break?

Open this shell in Notepad++, and then check if the line break is `UNIX(LF)` in the lower right corner.
If not, click the text `Windows (CR LF)` and then click `Convert to UNIX(LF)`.

This works for me.