# How do I run bash shell scripts in cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a file called butcher and at the top of this file I put #!/bin/bash. The I changed permissions like so chmod 777 butcher. however when I try to run the script by typing butcher, I get this error: -bash: butcher: command not found. I'm not sure how to fix it, please help! Thank you in advance! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file would have to be on your $PATH for your system to find it and execute it. Otherwise, the entire path to the file would have to be specified.

To show your path try:

```
echo $PATH
```

To run your script, either put it in one of those locations (such as /usr/local/bin), or go to the directory `butcher` is located in and run `./butcher`.